# How to initialize default float values in to array of structs?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

i have this bits of code :

```
typedef struct {
    kiss_fft_scalar r;
    kiss_fft_scalar i;
}kiss_fft_cpx;

kiss_fft_cpx* spectrum;
spectrum = (kiss_fft_cpx*)malloc( sizeof(kiss_fft_cpx)* 2024);
```

how to inialize both `r` and `i` members to 0? 
without looping all the array? and keep it cross platform .

Comment: by using calloc instead of malloc

Comment: use calloc instead of malloc? Depending on kiss_fft_scalar type calloc byte 0 will map to the kiss_fft_scalar 0 value (with normal float and double that is OK).

Comment: `calloc` or Fill the memory with zeros:
`memset(spectrum, 0, sizeof(kiss_fft_cpx));`

Comment: memset will be cross platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portably:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2024; ++i )
    spectrum[i].i = spectrum[i].r = 0;
```

Others have suggested using `calloc` or `memset`; those will only work if you know you are only coding for a platform that uses a floating point representation in which all-bits-zero means `0.f`, such as IEEE754.   (I'm assuming that `kiss_fft_scalar` is `float` as your title suggests).

If the size is known at compile-time then you can write:

```
kiss_fft_cpx spectrum[2024] = { 0 };
```

which will initialize all the values to `0`.

NB. [Don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and  even if size is not known exactly at compile-time but known to be small, you have the option to avoid malloc/free by writing `kiss_fft_cpx spectrum[size];` .

Comment: ++ for the remark on the return type of `malloc()` and the suggestion of the VLA.